# How do I disable Unity Dash search features like wiki and other websites?

Tags: unity, 14.04, unity-dash, search

On my system this not needed and affecting performance.

I'd like `unity-dash` to search only for `programs` and `documents` by default. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable the online searches very simply by setting this in the 'Security and Privacy' settings:

[image: Change 'when searching in the Dash, include online search results' to 'OFF']

Comment: Can I disable also "suggested" or "recommended" from found programs?